# Using DISTINCT with an EntityDataSource

Tags: asp.net, entitydatasource

I have an entity datasource (connetced to a SQL Server 2012 database) on a .NET v4 aspx page. My datasource declaration looks like this:

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="BlahBlah" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="name=BlahBlah" 
    DefaultContainerName="BlahBlah" EnableFlattening="False" 
    EntitySetName="vw_shop_ProductListWithIndivCats" 
    Where="it.Display =true" OrderBy="it.[DisplayPriority]" 
    Select="DISTINCT it.[ProductID], it.[Name], it.[Short_rubric],  it.[Price],  it.[Available], it.[Display], it.[ProductDetailLayoutID], it.[DisplayPriority] " >
```

The `WHERE` value is modified in code when the user interacts with the site.  The entity has more columns than in the `SELECT` statement

The data is displayed in a gridview and that works just fine except the `DISTINCT` keyword is not being respected, i.e. duplicate rows from the tables are being displayed in the gridview.

Any suggestions?

Some more details of the question.  The columns in the entity (which is a view) `vw_shop_ProductListWithIndivCats` are:

```
ProductID
Name
Short_rubric
Rubric
Price
Postage
Image_small
Image_Large
ImageType
Available
Display
ProductDetailLayoutID
DisplayPriority
CategoryID
Category
```

Most of the fields are derived form a products table. In the view there is a many to many join to a `Categories` table with the last two fields in mediated through the usual linking table.

In the user interface the user may selct products by categories and as products may have multiple categories, say n categopries,  the selct statement (without the distinct) produces x rows which as the view only contains fields form the products table will contain n duplicate rows.  I was expecting either DISTINCT or GROUP BY to dedupe the rows but neither does. I have conformed that I have the columns I think I have by temporarily putting in a list voiew that displays every column

Comment: `GROUP BY` only removes all duplicates if you include ALL columns. Is it possible to include the categories column in the select and group by clauses?

Comment: Nope as the the rows won't be the same.

Answer (score 1):

Why not try adding a `GROUP BY` clause which contains all of your columns? [MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.entitydatasource.groupby%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) And here is a link to the main [EntityDataSource article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.entitydatasource%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

As you probably know, in this case both `GROUP BY` and `DISTINCT` are likely to produce the ame query plan in SQL Server.

So you would change it to be like this (drop the `DISTINCT`):

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="BlahBlah" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="name=BlahBlah" 
    DefaultContainerName="BlahBlah" EnableFlattening="False" 
    EntitySetName="vw_shop_ProductListWithIndivCats" 
    Where="it.Display =true" OrderBy="it.[DisplayPriority]" 
    Select="it.[ProductID], it.[Name], it.[Short_rubric],  it.[Price],  it.[Available], [Display], it.[ProductDetailLayoutID], it.[DisplayPriority]"
    GroupBy="it.[ProductID], it.[Name], it.[Short_rubric],  it.[Price],  it.[Available], it.[Display], it.[ProductDetailLayoutID], it.[DisplayPriority]" />
```

Comment: Tried that before and it dodnlt work - also tried using MAX(it.ProductID) rather than just it.productID.

Comment: And I have also added a listcview that does no formatting displaying the data "raw" to check I really am getting identical rows

Comment: In what way did it not work? If you do a `select` and `group by` every column then it is the same as `select distinct`.

Comment: I still get duplicates.  I will explain more about data by editing my question